# Delete array from object in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

When I click on a button I load the function "DeleteFromlocalStorage" with the parameter "id".
This is my function "DeleteFromlocalStorage":

```
        function DeleteSessionFromLocalStorage(data)
    {
        var id_session = data;

        a = localStorage.getItem('session');

        alert(a);

    }
```

My `alert(a);` gives me this output:

> {"21114":{"id":"21114","external_id":"","sessiongroupid":"1844","eventid":"5588","order":"0","name":"localStorage HTML5 Session","description":"localstorage","starttime":"2013-04-23 12:00:00","endtime":"2013-04-23 13:30:00","speaker":"","location":"","mapid":"0","xpos":"0.000000","ypos":"0.000000","maptype":"plan","imageurl":"","presentation":"","organizer":"0","twitter":"","allowAddToFavorites":"0","allowAddToAgenda":"0","votes":"0","url":"","venueid":"0"},
>   "21115 :{"id":"21115","external_id":"","sessiongroupid":"1845","eventid":"5588","order":"0","name":"tweede","description":"tweede","starttime":"2013-04-03 00:00:00","endtime":"2013-04-04 00:00:00","speaker":"","location":"","mapid":"0","xpos":"0.000000","ypos":"0.000000","maptype":"plan","imageurl":"","presentation":"","organizer":"0","twitter":"","allowAddToFavorites":"0","allowAddToAgenda":"0","votes":"0","url":"","venueid":"0"},"21118":{"id":"21118","external_id":"","sessiongroupid":"1848","eventid":"5588","order":"0","name":"javascript session","description":"session about javascript","starttime":"2013-05-15 12:00:00","endtime":"2013-05-15 12:30:00","speaker":"","location":"waregem","mapid":"0","xpos":"0.000000","ypos":"0.000000","maptype":"plan","imageurl":"","presentation":"","organizer":"0","twitter":"","allowAddToFavorites":"0","allowAddToAgenda":"0","votes":"0","url":"","venueid":"0"}}

As you can see I have a json string. The key is always the id. Now I want to delete the json with the id = parameter id.

I will have to get the object and delete the subobject and restore the object in my localStorage. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks more like a JSON string to me ?

Comment: Where is the array you asked about?

Comment: If you know the key then use `localStorage.removeItem(key)`.

Comment: yes, sorry. it's a json string

Comment: For a start you JSON is valid see http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(obj in json) {       
            if(json[obj].id == id_session)
            {
                delete json[obj];

            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(json));
```

Get the objects, check every id of every object and delete the ones with the id = "id_session".

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but here is what you want to do:

Either `localStorage.removeItem(key);`

Or if ifs something within the localStorage JSON item then do:

```
  function DeleteSessionFromLocalStorage(data)
{
    var id_session = data;
    //Not sure but you might need to do JSON.parse(a) after to get it
    a = localStorage.getItem('session');

    delete a.data
    alert(a);

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I will have to get the object and delete the subobject and restore the object in my localStorage. Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample just looks like a javascript object to me. In which case you can use the 'delete' keyword. Good discussion here:

[How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

So something like

delete a["21114"]

Comment: Doesn't work. I will have to get the object and delete the subobject and restore the object in my localStorage. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: if 'localStorage.getItem('session');' is actually returning a string (which your question is not accurately showing) then you need to turn it into a javascript object. var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')); delete obj["key"];